# URL redirect for all branches under one tree but excluding certain file extensions

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, .net-2.0

.Net 2.0/IIS-7

I want to redirect

abc.com\GroupRequests\FirstGroup

to a handler abc.com\GroupRequests\grouprequesthandler.ashx
but I want all *.aspx files  in abc.com\GroupRequests\FirstGroup to be accessed using their original URL.

prefer config solution instead of code

Comment: Very well detailed question and hence the upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses URLRewriter which is available in IIS7. It is independent of your .net version.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewritePartner">
          <match url="^Partner/([A-Za-z]+)/(.+)" ignoreCase="false"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Handler/Partner.aspx?partner={R:1}&amp;query={R:2}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```